# Does PetaPoco also support OData like Entity Framework?

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2, petapoco

Can I use oData with PetaPoco also? I have a requirement where I need to filter the records by passing more than one input parameters. The method will be a WebAPI method.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, At the time exploring [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint) link, I found this quote *"Web API OData does not require EF. Use any data-access layer that can translate database entities into models."*

It means PetaPoco should also support OData.

Answer (score 0):

PetaPoco maintainer here.

No PetaPoco doesn't support OData and most likely never will.

The reason why is the mapping to and from OData for all supported DBs would be a too much work.